# Can you swap the keycaps from the Wireless Keyboard with a MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have a bit of an unusual question. I want to know whether it is possible to swap the keycaps of the Apple Wireless Keyboard with the MacBook Air (2017) keycaps. I like the white keycaps on the wireless keyboard on my MacBook and I wondered if it would be possible to swap them?

Would it be easy to do at home? Would there be any repercussions? Should I be aware of anything? **Will it even work?**

Comment: I don't believe these keyboards use the same mechanism, so I think it unlikely.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the case, however, can the mechanisms be separated from the keycaps? Instead of swapping the entire key, you just swap the keycap.

Comment: As far as I know **ALL** keyboards (mostly) work that way. Look for keycap replacement pics and videos online you may get lucky and see something that might help.